Access Denied issue - Connected App - Token
I'm encountering an issue with the token exchange flow in Salesforce. The API works as expected in our dev environment but fails in the QA sandbox, returning the following error:
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"end-user denied authorization"}
Here’s what we've done so far:
Verified profile access, Remote Site Settings, and enabled the Token Exchange Handler.
Followed the implementation steps in this blog: https://medium.com/@rjallu01/salesforce-token-exchange-flow-with-okta-90f0cafb4edc
API Details:

Endpoint: baseurl/services/oauth2/token?
Body Parameters:
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
subject_token_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token
client_id: (client IDhere)
client_secret: (client secret here)
subject_token: (subject token here)

Any insights into what could be missing or misconfigured in the QA

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Your example is somewhat Minimal, not Complete and therefore not Reproducible.

Check which checkboxes you have ticked in the API (Enable OAuth Settings) for your Connected App and make sure you are passing the data these options require.

Thank you, @PhilW, for your reply! I’ve double-checked that the settings and parameters in QA are exactly the same as in dev. The only changes I made were updating the endpoint, client ID, client secret, and subject token for QA. Unfortunately, it’s still not working.
One difference I noticed between the environments is that QA has SSO set up with an IdP, while dev does not. Could this SSO configuration be causing the issue? Any guidance would be appreciated!

The client credentials flow is working in QA, and we’re able to retrieve both access and refresh tokens with it. However, when we use the same System Admin credentials for the user flow, it fails.
